# Make org-mode not to insert day name in timestamps

Tags: org-mode

When I insert timestamps, even if by using the calendar, org inserts something like `<2016-10-20 Thu>`. However, I sometimes have to use machines with a different locale, which inserts `<2016-10-20 cs>`.

This, of course, I can parse, but it makes my (otherwise fully English) Org files look inconsistent. Given that Org doesn't parse the day name and inserts it for pure readability reasons[citation needed], is there a way to prevent Org inserting it at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can customize the variable `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` and remove the `%a` from the default. Note you also need to set the `org-display-custom-times` variable to something other than nil.

Comment: I don’t really want to mess with `org-display-custom-times` (and it seems I don’t really have to). I simply removed existing day name abbreviations with a regex-replace, and set my `org-time-stamp-formats`

Answer (score 1):

Although a custom format suggested by @icarus seems to be a good idea, I generally like the standard Org-mode format of `%Y-%m-%d` and `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M` (without that pesky `%a` part). As the only thing I wanted to get rid of is the name of the day, I ended up setting `org-time-stamp-formats` (I use `use-package`; if you don’t use such package managers, this `setq` should go into `after-init-hook`; otherwise `org.el`’s `defvar` will overwrite your preference.)

```
(use-package org
  :config
  (setq org-time-stamp-formats '("<%Y-%m-%d>" . "<%Y-%m-%d %H:%M>"))
```

*Note*: I also found out [from the docs](http://orgmode.org/manual/Creating-timestamps.html) that I can update the day name <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> if it is wrong, but that’s just an overkill for my situation.

Comment: The `org-time-stamp-formats` is declared with `defconst` in my version (24.5.1) of emacs, which is why I didn't suggest changing it.

Comment: Good point, I haven’t checked that (and I guess that’s why it got overwritten if I put it under `:init` instead of `:config`). I will experiment with `org-time-stamp-custom-formats`, then.